# MongoDB - Match the key

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to `$match` in a MongoDB, the number of documents in thousands, so looking for dynamic sol:

`$doc.k` equal to `$info.data.k` after `k`, `$match` then we have a document that contains only information that `$matchs`, see the expected output document. If you have any questions let me know.

```
[
  {
    "doc": {
      "k": "ABC",
      "v": {
        "sec": 0
      }
    },
    "info": [
      {
        "data": [
          {
            "k": "XYZ",
            "v": {
              "know": "alpha"
            }
          },
          {
            "k": "ABC",
            "v": {
              "know": "alpha"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The expected output document will look like this

```
[
  {
    "doc": {
      "k": "ABC",
      "v": {
        "sec": 0
      }
    },
    "info": [
      {
        "data": [
          {
            "k": "ABC",
            "v": {
              "know": "alpha"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$set` - Update `info` field.

   1.1. `$map` - As `info` is an array, need to iterate each document in the `info` array and return a new array.

   1.1.1. `$filter` - Filter the document by `doc.k` and current iterate `k` value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      info: {
        $map: {
          input: "$info",
          in: {
            data: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$$this.data",
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$doc.k",
                    "$$this.k"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FhQzg3_zGpf)

Comment: Thanks for comment, but if its not matach (`$info.data.k`), how we can set the condition ?  then we can print the message "Not match or not available"

Comment: Perhaps you need `$match` stage after `$set`. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/39JdJD_Xxr1)